# TREE-like sequence with Higman's lemma

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Since Kruskal's tree theorem is a generalization of Higman's lemma, and the famous TREE function is based on Kruskal's tree theorem, one could try to define an analogous "WORD" function.

WORD($n$) is the largest $m$ such that there is a sequence $W_1,\ldots,W_m$ of words over an $n$-ary alphabet where $W_i$ has at most $i$ letters, such that $W_i \le W_j$ (subsequence order) does not hold for any $i<j\le m$.

The lemma doesn't immediately prove that $m$ is bounded, but I think this does: otherwise by the pigeonhole principle infinitely many of these sequences start with some word $x$, of these infinitely many follow with $y$ etc, so we can have an infinite subsequence-free sequence $(x,y,\ldots)$, contradicting the lemma.

If I didn't mess up anything this is kind of an obvious thing to define, and yet I couldn't find anything about it. What can be said about WORD($n$)? How does it compare to TREE($n$) (besides "$\le$")?

Comment: I don't know much about this area, but this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4399.pdf) by Schmitz and Schnoebelen addresses the broader problem of bounding "controlled bad sequences" arising from Higman's Lemma. In particular, there's a bound immediately following Proposition 5.2 which seems to apply to the WORD function (since we have WORD$(p) = L_{\Gamma_p^*, g}(1)$ for $g(x) = x+1$). The papers mentioned in the "Comparison with Existing Work" section might also be relevant.